# Rails Application and CKEditor not resizing images (not using proper html)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I am having trouble getting ckeditor to properly resize images in my Rails application.  When I look at the html in it appears that the height and width parameters are not showing up.  When I leave the text unsanitized in rails the height and width parameters appear as below, which is obviously is using a colon in lieu of "=" followed by a number in " ".

```
<img alt="" src="/ckeditor_assets/pictures/1/content_world.png" style="float: left; width: 100px; height: 100px; " />
```

Does anyone have any clue how this can be adjusted somewhere in the config.js or somewhere else that will cause these parameters to result in proper html?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The default configuration of CKEditor sets the image size in the style (yes, I don't like either, let's not argue about it).

You can look at the "Output HTML" sample to get the code to generate width and height attributes instead.